# Poltergeist:TimeOutError while trying to click on a particular link

Tags: rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I am trying to click on a link and it shows 'Unable to click on the link' because of time-out error. But the link is visible on the page.Here is the snippet.

```
require 'spec_helper'

      describe 'Test this page', :js => true do
        it "test sample" do 
        # Resize the screen to System co-ordinates
        page.driver.resize(1366,768)

        # URL to be triggered
        visit("https://URL")
        sleep 5
        puts "Hit Page"
        page.driver.render('HitPage.jpg', :full =>true)

        # Sign in with Google credentials
        click_link "Sign in with Google Oauth2"
        sleep 2
    end
        # Entering credentials of Google Auth
        it "Enter credentials" do
            puts "Session"
        page.driver.render('googlepage.jpg', :full =>true)
        fill_in "Email",:with => "username"
        fill_in "Passwd",:with => "password"
        click_button "Sign in"
        sleep 5
        page.driver.render('loggedin.jpg', :full =>true)
    end
    end
```

Link is displayed in the screenshot(HitPage.jpg) and its clickable too. But while execting through 'rspec spec/test_spec.rb', output displays timeout error as follows.

```
Failure/Error: click_link "Sign in with Google Oauth2"

 Capybara::Poltergeist::TimeoutError:
   Timed out waiting for response to {"name":"click","args":[1,0]}. It's possible that this happened because something took a very long time (for example a page load was slow). If so, setting the Poltergeist :timeout option to a higher value will help (see the docs for details). If increasing the timeout does not help, this is probably a bug in Poltergeist - please report it to the issue tracker.
 # ./lib/capybara/poltergeist/web_socket_server.rb:87:in `rescue in send'
 # ./lib/capybara/poltergeist/web_socket_server.rb:83:in `send'
 # ./lib/capybara/poltergeist/server.rb:33:in `send'
 # ./lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:312:in `command'
 # ./lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb:167:in `click'
 # ./lib/capybara/poltergeist/node.rb:17:in `command'
 # ./lib/capybara/poltergeist/node.rb:116:in `click'
 # ./spec/test_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 52.51 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

But it clicks on the link and continues with the next execution by entering email and password.

Any idea why this time out is displayed though the link is clicked?

```
Poltergeist -1.5.1
Capybara-2.4.4
ruby - 1.9.3
```